# How to map object instead of array with JSON API using React JS + Redux

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

I want to map of over object instead of Array, my current code works great with Array map but I am getting data undefined if I map object using state props with redux.

**My JSON Format:**

```
{
"exclusive_collection": {
        "id": "0",
        "image_url": "media/mobilebanner/default/ExclusiveCollection-en_new.jpg"
    },
    "exclusive_brands": [
        {
            "id": "1268",
            "is_featured": "0",
            "name": "Spongelle",
            "image_url": "media/catalog/category/Spongelle.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": "756",
            "is_featured": "0",
            "name": "Black Up",
            "image_url": "media/catalog/category/Black-Up.jpg"
        },
    ],}
```

**Reducer function :**

```
export function items(state = [], action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return action.items;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Slider from "react-slick";

class ShopbyCategory extends Component {
  render() {
    let shopbycategoryArray = [];
    let shop_by_category = this.props.items.shop_by_category

    for (let key in shop_by_category) {
        shopbycategoryArray.push(shop_by_category[key]);
        return (

        <section className="celebrityslider">
        <div className="row">
        <div className="widget-title"><h3>Shop By Category</h3></div>
        </div>  
        <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12 no-padding">  
        <Slider {...slidersettings}>
        {this.props.items.shop_by_category.map((item) => (
                <div key={item.id} className="slider-item">
                    <a href="#"><img src={item.image_url} className="img-responsive"/></a>
                </div>
            ))}  
        </Slider>
        </div>
        </div>        
        </section>
        );
    }

    if (this.props.hasErrored) {
        return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
    }

    if (this.props.isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading…</p>;
    }
    return (
        null
    );

  }

}
```

I am able to get the data of exclusive_brands array with the code above in my component.

But I am not sure how to get the data of **exclusive_collection** I am always getting undefined if I am doing the below :

```
let exclusive_collection = this.props.items.exclusive_collection
console.log (exclusive_collection);
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me to map this with redux or in other way. Thanks

Comment: Please share more information. What does `items` referenced in the reducer look like ? What is passed as `props` to `ShopbyCategory` component from redux ? I do not see `shop_by_category` key anywhere in your reducer or JSON. How are you able to access that variable ?

Comment: Please see the `action.js for items` reference `export function itemsFetchDataSuccess(items) {
    return {
        type: 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
        items
    };
}`

I have cut down the JSON file for this specific question, `shop_by_category` is the array in my original JSON. Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: As per your code, it should work fine if your actions, reducers and the JSON array is as you say. Unless the exact JSON pertaining to `shop_by_category` and the method in which it is converted to `ShopbyCategory`'s props is provided, we cannot debug further

Comment: Have you tried `Object.values(exclusive_collection).map((val) => { return ... }` ?

Comment: I have not tried this, but I am able to get the data now without map because there is only one image which I need to fetch with API. `let exclusive_collection = this.props.items.exclusive_collection` `<img src={exclusive_collection.image_url} className="img-responsive"/>`